# Markdown Preview Enhanced VSCode run code chunk

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run code cells as the Markdown Preview Enhanced allows.  However, when I try to do this, I get no output.  I have enabled script execution as the documentation suggests.  If anyone else uses this wonderful extension and knows how to do it, please let me know.  Here is an example of a block that I have tried.  I have also tried with `{cmd = True}` and no brackets.

````
```python {cmd='usr/local/bin/env'}
print('hi')
\``` # That slash is just to escape the backticks within this code block
````

Comment: I was struggling with the same problem when I realized that I was using the basic markdown extension to preview the file instead of the "enhanced" preview you can get by clicking on the top-right icon added by mpe (or through Ctrl+K V).

Answer (score 0):

````
```python {cmd}
print('hi')
```
````

produces

```
hi
```

as expected.

Possibly your installed python is not on your path - check by running python in the terminal.