# How do I run a chunk of (Anaconda) Python code in a Markdown document in VS Code?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, markdown

I have some fenced Python code in a Markdown document in VS Code. The Python code input is parsed and rendered, but the Python code is not interpreted and its output is not rendered.

MWE:
In the Markdown .md file, I tried variations along the lines of:

````
    ```python {cmd = '/Users/john/anaconda3/bin/python'}
    x = 3
    y = 5
    print(x + y)
    ```
````

The code chunk input is rendered in Markdown, but not its output. [I get an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsKFp.png) instead of the answer 8. This seems to work for some but not for others, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65055139/markdown-preview-enhanced-vscode-run-code-chunk) in Stackoverflow.

This may be because of one or both of:

1. I have the Anaconda distribution of Python. Neither anaconda nor python is in PATH on my Mac, this being the default setup for Anaconda: see [Anaconda FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com). PATH is dynamically and locally prepended only when a conda environment is activated. This is to avoid package dependency issues.
2. VS Code may have a security setting forbidding code execution to avoid issues with malicious code. FYI, I have the "Markdown Preview Enhanced" extension in VS Code with the "enable script execution" toggled to ON.

I have also tried:

1. adding python to PATH using `conda init tcsh`
2. toggling off and on the "enable script execution" setting in the "Markdown Preview Enhanced" extension of VS Code
3. running this in a Jupyter Notebook .ipynb file in VS Code--all Python code outside the Markdown chunk executes, but not the code inside
4. replacing `/Users/john/anaconda3/bin/python` by `/Users/john/anaconda3/envs/hello_py/bin/python` in the fenced code chunk
5. using double quotes rather than single quotes

Alternatives would be to use R, knitr, reticulate, but I do not know how to make R access the Anaconda base or virtual environment.

Can you please help? Thanks in advance! Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround: instead of executing fenced Python code in a `.md` Markdown document in VS Code, just include Markdown in a `.ipynb` Python notebook within VS Code.

MWE. Input in a Markdown cell followed by a Python cell:

```
$$ \int_{-\infty}^0 e^x \,dx \;=\; 1$$

from math import exp
from scipy.integrate import quad
print('{0:.10f}'.format(quad(exp, -10000, 0)[0]))
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJvFB.png)